# ffmpeg: concat video and audio files

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg

Is it possible to concatenate multiple files, if some of the files are videos with audio and some are audio only. The end result should look like this:

```
--------------------------------------------------------
|###(v/a)### | ### (a) ### | ### (a) ### | ###(v/a)### |
--------------------------------------------------------

v/a: video + audio
a  : audio only (blank screen)
```

I tried to do it with the following command:

```
ffmpeg 
-i chunk1.mp4 
-i chunk2.m4a 
-i chunk3.mp4
-filter_complex "[0:v:0] [0:a:0] [1:v:0] [1:a:0] [2:v:0] [2:a:0] concat=n=3:v=1:a=1 [v] [a]"
-map "[v]" -map "[a]" -strict -2 result.mp4
```

So I tried to only use the audio track from input 1 (`[1:a:0]`) but unfortunately, I'm getting this error message:

```
Stream specifier ':v:0' in filtergraph description [0:v:0] [0:a:0] [1:v:0] [1:a:0] [2:v:0] [2:a:0] concat=n=3:v=1:a=1 [v] [a] matches no streams.
```

I thought that this must be possible somehow, since I can also combine a large audio file and a small video with ffmpeg. The result would then be a video file where the last frame just freezes but the audio still plays along. I would like to achieve the same result with either a frozen last frame or simply a black frames. Is this possible?

Comment: What's the resolution and framerate of the videos?

Comment: @Mulvya I don't know the resolution. All video chunks will definitely have the same one but that can vary from task to task. The same goes for the framerate. So I guess, I would like ffmpeg to just adopt whatever the other video chunks have. If that is not possible, and I need to explicitly specify framerate and/or resolution, I'm sure I can read those parameters manually via ffprobe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the command given in the Q, use

```
ffmpeg -i chunk1.mp4 -i chunk2.m4a -i chunk3.mp4 -filter_complex \
       "color=black:s=WxH:r=N:d=T[1v]; \
       [0:v:0] [0:a:0] [1v] [1:a:0] [2:v:0] [2:a:0] concat=n=3:v=1:a=1 [v] [a]"
-map "[v]" -map "[a]" -strict -2 result.mp4
```

where `WxH` is the resolution of the videos, `N` the framerate, and `T` the duration of the audio file.

Comment: By the way, I found that framerate and duration both don't seem to matter. In any way, ffmpeg will stretch the video to fit the length of the audio. So, is there any downside if I just specify r=20:d=1 every time?